# Wordpress responsiveness and content for mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, content-management-system, slideshow

I am trying to set up my own wordpress website and have a couple of questions.

At the moment I show a background video on the homepage. I am wondering if it is possible to replace this video with an image slideshow on the mobile view?

Also, how can I generally show different content on desktop/mobile view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: This question is too broad. You'll need to attempt some code for a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Media queries.

So for example you could say:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #video-div {display:none;}
    #Slideshow-div  {display:block;}
 }
```

The code above means the video will not display unless the width of the browser window is equal to or more than 800px.

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #Slideshow-div {display:none;}
    #video-div {display:block;}
}
```

This code is saying that as long as the screen is more than 800px wide, the slideshow will not appear.

You can play around with the px amount and have many different media queries.